# Printing exact Array Object

Tags: php, arrays

I am using

```
<?php foreach ($totals as $total) { ?>
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;" colspan="4"><b><?php echo $total['title']; ?>:</b></td>
<td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $total['text']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

But I seem to be rusty in PHP how do i access the first or any given object?
I have tried
echo $totals[0]; but doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Show your full array please

Comment: Show full array what you want to print or you can use print_r($total) to check what inside

Comment: First print_r($totals); and see the array contents. Then make sure you see the contents in the array as expected. The code seems ok to me

Comment: Thanks.
So I got
"Array ( [order_total_id] => 3439 [order_id] => 862 [code] => total [title] => Total [text] => 215,00Kr. [value] => 215.0000 [sort_order] => 9 )"
How do I get any of the objects in that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object and arrays are quiet different

objects can be accessed trough `$object->parameter` while we access arrays through `$array['parameter']`

now if your object has an implementation of **Traversable**, you can still loop over an object as it was an array but not access it as `$object['parameter']`

Your object would need at least **ArrayAccess** to do that.

Edit: Little update on OP's answers in comments.

If you however have an array of an array, you can simply access a specific element as
`$array['row']['parameter']`

If your $totals object is a traversable object this works in a similar way :
`$object->array['parameter']` or the other way around as an array of objects `$array['object']->parameter

or in this case `$totals[0]['order_total_id']`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Its almost what I am looking too i guess.
I want to print/echo Array ( [order_total_id] => 3439) Other than all the objects in the array. Is that possible?

Comment: you could try an array search if you want to find a specific row with a specific value and then just print that row off

Answer (score 0):

To see what's really in your array, you can make a dump of it :

```
echo <pre>; //to see with proper formating
var_dump($totals);
echo </pre>;
```

With $totals[0], you are normally on the first element of your array.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried

```
<?php
for($i=0; $i<count($totals); $i++) 
{
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;" colspan="4"><b><?php echo $totals[$i]['title']; ?>:</b></td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px; border-right: 1px solid #DDDDDD; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; text-align: right; padding: 7px;"><?php echo $totals[$i]['text']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

?>

Comment: I think it would be easier to use a foreach loop in cases like this, just like the OP did.